# CGLIB Enhancement failed:argument type mismatch

Tags: hibernate, cglib, type-mismatch

I`m getting following error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: CGLIB Enhancement failed: sk.statistics.isis.conceptsvocab.jpa.entities.VocabDomain
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxy(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:119)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBProxyFactory.getProxy(CGLIBProxyFactory.java:72)
at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.createProxy(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:402)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createProxy(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3483)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.createProxyIfNecessary(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:298)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:126)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:905)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:873)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:590)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:412)
at org.hibernate.engine.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:139)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:877)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:752)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2228)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2125)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2120)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:361)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1148)
at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
at sk.statistics.isis.conceptsvocab.adminmodule.services.impl.SubdomainsServiceImpl.getAllSubdomainLocalizationNamesForSpecificLocalization(SubdomainsServiceImpl.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy31.getAllSubdomainLocalizationNamesForSpecificLocalization(Unknown Source)
at sk.statistics.isis.conceptsvocab.adminmodule.ui.SubdomainsList.initContent(SubdomainsList.java:210)
at sk.statistics.isis.conceptsvocab.adminmodule.mainWindow.MainPanel.selectWindowToDisplay(MainPanel.java:63)
at sk.statistics.isis.conceptsvocab.adminmodule.mainWindow.MainPanel.access$0(MainPanel.java:50)
at sk.statistics.isis.conceptsvocab.adminmodule.mainWindow.MainPanel$MainPanelListener.valueChange(MainPanel.java:98)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.hibernate.repackage.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setCallbacksHelper(Enhancer.java:616)
at org.hibernate.repackage.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.setThreadCallbacks(Enhancer.java:609)
at org.hibernate.repackage.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.registerCallbacks(Enhancer.java:578)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxyInstance(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:129)
at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.cglib.CGLIBLazyInitializer.getProxy(CGLIBLazyInitializer.java:116)
... 69 more
```

VocabDomain listing:

```
/**
* The persistent class for the VOCAB_DOMAINS database table.
* 
*/
@Entity
@Table(name="VOCAB_DOMAINS")
public class VocabDomain implements Serializable {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 202977208021067034L;
private Long domainid;
private Long optlockversion;
private Set<VocabDomainsLoc> vocabDomainsLocs;
private Set<VocabSubdomain> vocabSubdomains;

public VocabDomain() {
}


@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name="VOCAB_DOMAINS_DOMAINID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="SEQ_DOMAIN_ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="VOCAB_DOMAINS_DOMAINID_GENERATOR")    
public Long getDomainid() {
    return this.domainid;
}

public void setDomainid(Long domainid) {
    this.domainid = domainid;
}

@Version
public Long getOptlockversion() {
    return this.optlockversion;
}

public void setOptlockversion(Long optlockversion) {
    this.optlockversion = optlockversion;
}


//bi-directional many-to-one association to VocabDomainsLoc
@OneToMany(mappedBy="vocabDomain",fetch=FetchType.LAZY) 
public Set<VocabDomainsLoc> getVocabDomainsLocs() {
    return this.vocabDomainsLocs;
}

public void setVocabDomainsLocs(Set<VocabDomainsLoc> vocabDomainsLocs) {
    this.vocabDomainsLocs = vocabDomainsLocs;
}


//bi-directional many-to-one association to VocabSubdomain
@OneToMany(mappedBy="vocabDomain",fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public Set<VocabSubdomain> getVocabSubdomains() {
    return this.vocabSubdomains;
}

public void setVocabSubdomains(Set<VocabSubdomain> vocabSubdomains) {
    this.vocabSubdomains = vocabSubdomains;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (this == other) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!(other instanceof VocabDomain)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (this.getDomainid() == null) {
        return false;
    }       
    VocabDomain castOther = (VocabDomain) other;
    if (castOther.getDomainid() == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return this.getDomainid().equals(castOther.getDomainid());

}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 211;
    int hash = 223;
    hash = hash * prime + (this.getDomainid() != null ?     this.getDomainid().hashCode() : 1);
    return hash;
}       
}
```

The code fails during execution of this command:
    Query q = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("SELECT vsd FROM VocabSubdomain vsd LEFT JOIN vsd.vocabSubdomainsLocs");
    List vsdl = q.list();

---

my dependencies in pom.xml

```
<spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>3.4.0.GA</hibernate.version>


<dependencies>

<dependency>
    <!-- na poradi zalezi -->
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-jcl</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>        
      <groupId>sk.statistics.isis.conceptsvocab.jpa</groupId>
      <artifactId>ConceptsVocabJpa</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>   

    <!--  Vaadin dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
        <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--  J2EE dependencies -->
<dependency>
<groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
<version>2.5</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
    <!-- Portlet dependencies -->       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>${portal.scope}</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.portals.bridges</groupId>
        <artifactId>portals-bridges-common</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!-- Ldap configuration start -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>ldapbp</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Ldap configuration end -->         
    <!-- Hibernate configuration -->
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
      <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
      <version>1.1</version>
      <scope>${websphere.scope}</scope>
      <!--  TODO: pre profil na websphere tu treba dat provided -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
      <!--  vynechaj jta transakcny management, websphere ma vlastny -->
      <exclusions>
          <exclusion>
              <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
              <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
          </exclusion>
          <exclusion>
              <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
              <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
          </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
   </dependency>        
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-cglib-repack</artifactId>
      <version>2.1_3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>cglib</groupId>
      <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>   
    <!-- Slf4j over commons logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>           
    <!-- 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>           
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    --> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.16</version>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: What version of hibernate and cglib are you using? This is most likely a version conflict.

Comment: Cglib repack 2.1_3 and hibernate 3.4.0 GA

Comment: I think you need to get rid of the hibernate-cglib-repack - https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=994331

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The the issue is due to the hibernate-cglib-repack. If you remove that dependency it should work.

Background :
In one version of hibernate they decided to repackage the cglib classes to be under org.hibernate packages.  The change ignored to handle references to class names encoded as string. So it was reverted back as the change was not required once hibernate code was upgraded to use the 2.2 version of cglib.

Hibernate bugs related to this issue.

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-3504

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2875

Relevant extracts

> The plan is to no longer use the repackaging of cglib and to migrate
>   to 2.2 now that it has been released. In fact this is already done by
>   Scott in SVN : HHH-3832
>
> Unfortunately we did not have much of a choice when we made this
>   change. We had been waiting on cglib 2.2 release for well over a year
>   at that point and had gotten no response from our multiple attempts to
>   contact them. And I am talking about over a year of no releases at
>   all, not betas, crs, nada. I did not realize about the strings inside
>   Enhancer. I thought the shade plugin was supposed to handle FQN of
>   classes as strings. Guess not  At this point, considering cglib 2.2 is
>   out its probably best to go ahead and use it for Hibernate 3.5 instead
>   of the repack. For 3.3 we will need to continue to use the repack
>   unless cglib 2.1 and 2.2 are bytecode compatible (which they are not
>   to my understanding). I'll investigate whether that has been addresses
>   in the shade plugn yet, or what other options might be. Also, there is
>   a project we use to produce the shaded repack:
>   http://anonsvn.jboss.org/repos/hibernate/cglib/ So, whose gonna
>   volunteer to see what it takes to get cglib 2.2 working with
>   hibernate?

Comment: I`ve changed hibernate to 3.5.6-Final also with annotations.
Using cglib 2.2.2. It`s now working.